# Django Development server displaying wrong project data

Tags: django, django-dev-server

I am able to access the django development server 127.0.0.1:8000 even without running "python manage.py runserver". It is displaying the previously created project website. Even when I run manage.py runserver from a different project it still show the data from previous project.

Why is this happening? How to recover?

Comment: This means your old server has not shut down, but is running "in the background" perhaps no longer with a terminal allocated to it. Depending on the operating system, you should look for the process that "listens" to the port, and kill that process.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run your server on a different port

```
python manage.py runserver 7000
```